# Import-Module : The specified module 'msonline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, module

Error :

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'msonline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory
```

The error pops up when I try to load the module by typing :

```
Import-Module MSOnline
```

tried to install the Azure AD powershell module on my computer so I'd be able to make PSSession using the MSONLINE cmdlets.

After I installed the Microsoft Online Services Sign-in Assistant (version7.250.4556.0) and then installed the latest Windows Azure AD Module for Windows Powershell, I get the above error in the title.

I can do following cmd and get output :

```
(get-item C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline\Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.PSModule.dll).VersionInfo.FileVersion
```

Output :
**1.0.8362.1**

I was originally following this guide :

https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/installing_the_windows_azure_ad_module_for_windows_powershell.htm

I can confirm on another computer where this Module is working fine that the files in the path (where the module files should reside) are the same as my computer that isn't working :

*C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\MSOnline*

I've already rebooted after installation. I've tried to install different version of the Azure AD Module from [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/28552.microsoft-azure-active-directory-powershell-module-version-release-history.aspx) to no avail.

Hardware/Software Version info :
Computer : Microsoft Surface Pro 3
OS Version : Windows 8.1 64-bit
PowerShell Version : Major **4** Minor **0** Build  **-1** Revision **-1**

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you running the x86 or x64 PowerShell console / ISE?

Comment: I believe a x64 PowerShell process. I ran :
`PS C:\> [Environment]::Is64BitProcess`
_True_

Comment: and its in the console, not ISE...but running the same command in the ISE gives the same error too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out the issue.

There are 2 binaries that you need to install to get this working :

- Microsoft Online Services Sign-In Assistant for IT Professionals RTW
- Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell

Both of these need to be the 64bit version to work together (in my case since I have a x64bit OS).

When I was trying to install the Online Services Sign-In Assistant through IE it kept giving me the 32bit MSI, even though I was asking for the 64bit installer.

I realized this after I tried to save the file, instead of just hitting RUN on the download.

Once I switched to chrome I was able to download the 64bit version.

After I had the 64bit version of both binaries installed everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Well before you can run `Import-Module MSOnline`, run `Install-Module MSOnline`, you may need to answer `‘Y’` to proceed

Then, run `Import-Module MSOnline` and you are good to go!