# Unknown cmdlets error when running PowerShell script with Python

Tags: python, powershell

I have a PS script that creates a new user in Office 365. I'm using the MSOnline and AzureAD modules in order to perform everything I need.

I need to run the PS script from my Python script but it doesn't work, I get the ["not recognized cmdlet"](https://pastebin.com/Btd4acf4) error.

The PS script is pretty basic, it fails at the connection to the Msol service and just continues on as if everything is ok.

```bsh
$LiveCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $Admin_User, $Admin_Password
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PsSession $Session -AllowClobber
Connect-MsolService -Credential $LiveCred
Connect-AzureAD -Credential $LiveCred
```

I tried adding `import-module` for both MSOnline and AzureAD but it didn't work. It's worth mentioning that the script, on it's own, does work and everything is fine. I'll add another piece of info: I have another PS script that my Python one executes and it's the creation of a new user in our local AD. That one works flawlessly and I'm not sure why.

I'm executing the PS with this simple test:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '.\\O365UserCreation.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

I also checked `$env:PSModulePath` which seems fine and returns this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules`

Also, I have the right modules installed:

[image].

Any help would be great. I can't seem to find anything online regarding this.

Comment: Try to use `import-module` after `Import-pssession`

Comment: @Vad thanks, but it still doesn't work.
The specified module 'MSOnline' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.

Comment: may you have problem with version of module 32\64 bit. Look at this topic [topic](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/746408c6-fa64-4b57-8cfd-599e092fcfe4/importmodule-the-specified-module-msonline-was-not-loaded-because-no-valid-module-file-was?forum=WindowsAzureAD)  to check version psmodule type `[Environment]::Is64BitProcess` and this topic must be helpful [help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829788/import-module-the-specified-module-msonline-was-not-loaded-because-no-valid)

Comment: @Vad the command returned true. The topic kinda gave me a lead but I checked most of the stuff written there already. I have everything installed and I played between folders, tried to import the module directly from both folders.

Comment: You can troubleshoot this kind of thing a lot better by using Try..Catch together with -ErrorAction Stop for your commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the I had Python 32 bit installed. Installing the 64 bit version fixed this.